# Find in subdocument MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to first find the document by *_id*. 
Then in the document to find subdocument which have a Time field is greater than the parameter *lastTime*

```
var filter = builder.Eq("_id", symbol) & builder.Gt("Update.Time", lastTime);
var result = await MongoDb.CollectionName.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

This example has a result of 0.

How to write this query? I need get this subdocument "Update" or last 3 sub-subdocument

The document has the following structure

```
{
  {"_id", symbol},
  {"Update", [
              {"_id", number}, {"Time", sometime}, {"Version", versionNumber}, 
              {"_id", number}, {"Time", sometime}, {"Version", versionNumber},
              {"_id", number}, {"Time", sometime}, {"Version", versionNumber},
              {"_id", number}, {"Time", sometime}, {"Version", versionNumber},}
             ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If mongodb console will work an example:

```
> db.doc.save({
   "_id":"123", 
   "update":[
       {"_id":'1', "time":'345', "Version":'3'}, 
       {"_id":'2', "time":'234', "Version":'4'}
    ]
})
> db.doc.findOne( { _id:"123", "update.time":{ $gt: 344 } } )
```

Then for C# Will can you to try ?

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("name");
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gt("update.time", 344);
var result = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

This [example](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/csharp/query/#greater-than-operator-gt)

UPD This can be:

```
var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("name");
var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
var filter  = builder.Eq("_id", id) & builder.Gt("update.time", 344);
var result  = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I actually saw this example. My problem is that I need a first identity by id. Because there are too many documents. First i need to find the document by id and then search in sub-document.

Comment: Your second example is written in my question. It doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Try using lambda expressions:

```
var lastTime = 1;
var result = collection.Find(x => x.Update.Contains(lastTime));
```

Comment: We discourage code-only answers here. Please edit your answer and explain how and why this answers the question.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, this specific answer does not try to answer this question. OP tries to filter subdocuments which are greater than a specific time.